# Extracting text data from files in different sub-directories raises "ValueError: substring not found"

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-science

I was trying to extract text data from files in different sub-directories and put the extracted data into pandas dataframes.

An example of the text data is given below:

> "EXAMINATION: CHEST PA AND LAT INDICATION: History: F with shortness of breath TECHNIQUE: Chest PA and lateral COMPARISON: FINDINGS: The cardiac mediastinal and hilar contours are normal. Pulmonary vasculature is normal. Lungs are clear. No pleural effusion or pneumothorax is present. Multiple clips are again seen projecting over the left breast. Remote leftsided rib fractures are also re demonstrated. IMPRESSION: No acute cardiopulmonary abnormality."

However, when attempting to execute the code given below, it produced the following error, how do I resolve this?

#### Error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-bbeeb452bdef> in <module>
     48         df = pd.DataFrame(columns=keywords)
     49         # Extract text
---> 50         result = extract_text_using_keywords(text, keywords)
     51         # Append list of extracted text to the end of the pandas df
     52         df.loc[len(df)] = result

<ipython-input-108-bbeeb452bdef> in extract_text_using_keywords(clean_text, keyword_list)
     39             for prev_kw, current_kw in zip(keyword_list, keyword_list[1:]):
     40                 prev_kw_index = clean_text.index(prev_kw)
---> 41                 current_kw_index = clean_text.index(current_kw)
     42                 extracted_texts.append(clean_text[prev_kw_index + len(prev_kw) + 2:current_kw_index])
     43                 if current_kw == keyword_list[-1]:

ValueError: substring not found
```

#### Code

```py
out = []
result = {}

for filename in glob.iglob('/content/sample_data/**/*.txt', recursive = True):
    
    out.append(filename)

print('File names: ',out)

for file in out:
      
        with open(file) as f:
          data = f.read()
          
    
        import re
        text = re.sub(r"[-_()\n\"#//@;<>{}=~|?,]*", "", data)
        text = re.sub(r'FINAL REPORT', '', text)
        text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text)
        print(text)

        keywords = ["INDICATION", "TECHNIQUE", "COMPARISON", "FINDINGS", "IMPRESSION"]

        # Create function to extract text between each of the keywords
        # Assumption
        def extract_text_using_keywords(clean_text, keyword_list):
            extracted_texts = []
            for prev_kw, current_kw in zip(keyword_list, keyword_list[1:]):
                prev_kw_index = clean_text.index(prev_kw)
                current_kw_index = clean_text.index(current_kw)
                extracted_texts.append(clean_text[prev_kw_index + len(prev_kw) + 2:current_kw_index])
                if current_kw == keyword_list[-1]:
                    extracted_texts.append(clean_text[current_kw_index + len(current_kw) + 2:len(clean_text)])
            return extracted_texts

        # Create empty pandas df with keywords as column names
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=keywords)
        # Extract text
        result = extract_text_using_keywords(text, keywords)
        # Append list of extracted text to the end of the pandas df
        df.loc[len(df)] = result

        #print(df)

        with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', None): # For diplaying full columns
          display(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ValueError` is raised by the function call [index()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) in the line `current_kw_index = clean_text.index(current_kw)` because `clean_text` does not contain the `current_kw` that the code is attempting to find.

It is likely that in one of your files, the `data` and therefore the `text` that your inputting to `result = extract_text_using_keywords(text, keywords)` does not contain either "INDICATION", "TECHNIQUE", "COMPARISON", "FINDINGS", or "IMPRESSION". So the easiest way to resolve this is to check which file is causing the issue and add the necessary keyword.

To make this debugging easier, you can update the `extract_text_using_keywords()` function to include a `try except` block to give you a more useful output for the `ValueError`. You can also update other parts of the code to deal with the subsequent issues that will follow as a result of being unable to find the keyword. A complete solution is as follows:

```py
import glob
import pandas as pd
import re

# Get & print all .txt file names with directory information
out = []
for filename in glob.iglob('content/sample_data/**/*.txt', recursive = True):
    out.append(filename)
print('File names: ', out)

# Define keywords
keywords = ["INDICATION", "TECHNIQUE", "COMPARISON", "FINDINGS", "IMPRESSION"]
# Create empty pandas df with keywords as column names
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=keywords)


# Create function to extract text between each of the keywords
def extract_text_using_keywords(clean_text, keyword_list):
    extracted_texts = []
    for prev_kw, current_kw in zip(keyword_list, keyword_list[1:]):
        try:            
            prev_kw_index = clean_text.index(prev_kw)
        except ValueError:
            print("Keyword {} was not found in the text.".format(prev_kw))
        try:
            current_kw_index = clean_text.index(current_kw)
        except ValueError:
            print("Keyword {} was not found in the text.".format(current_kw))
        try:
            extracted_texts.append(clean_text[prev_kw_index + len(prev_kw) + 2:current_kw_index])
            if current_kw == keyword_list[-1]:
                extracted_texts.append(clean_text[current_kw_index + len(current_kw) + 2:len(clean_text)])
        except UnboundLocalError:
            print("An index was not assigned for a particular keyword.")
    return extracted_texts


# Iterate over all .txt files
for file in out:
    with open(file) as f:
      data = f.read()

    text = re.sub(r"[-_()\n\"#//@;<>{}=~|?,]*", "", data)
    text = re.sub(r'FINAL REPORT', '', text)
    text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text)
    # print(text)

    # Extract text
    result = extract_text_using_keywords(text, keywords)

    # If all keywords and their results were found
    if len(result) == len(keywords):
        # Append list of extracted text to the end of the pandas df
        df.loc[len(df)] = result
    else:
        print("\nFailed to extract text for one or more keywords.\
        \nPlease check that {} are all present in the following text:\n\n{}\n".format(keywords, text))

# Display results
print(df)
# with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', None): # For diplaying full columns
#     display(df)
```

Produces the following error output when a keyword is not included (e.g. "TECHNIQUE"):

```
Keyword TECHNIQUE was not found in the text.
An index was not assigned for a particular keyword.
Keyword TECHNIQUE was not found in the text.

Failed to extract text for one or more keywords.
Please check that ['EXAMINATION', 'TECHNIQUE', 'COMPARISON', 'FINDINGS', 'IMPRESSION'] are all present in the following text:

 EXAMINATION: CHEST PA AND LAT INDICATION: F with new onset ascites eval for infection : Chest PA and lateral COMPARISON: None FINDINGS: There is no focal consolidation pleural effusion or pneumothorax Bilateral nodular opacities that most likely represent nipple shadows The cardiomediastinal silhouette is normal Clips project over the left lung potentially within the breast The imaged upper abdomen is unremarkable Chronic deformity of the posterior left sixth and seventh ribs are noted IMPRESSION: No acute cardiopulmonary process

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [INDICATION, TECHNIQUE, COMPARISON, FINDINGS, IMPRESSION]
Index: []
```

And produces the desired output when all keywords are included:

```
File names:  ['content/sample_data\\my_data.txt', 'content/sample_data\\my_data2.txt']
                                     INDICATION              TECHNIQUE COMPARISON                                           FINDINGS                        IMPRESSION
0  F with new onset ascites eval for infection   Chest PA and lateral       None   There is no focal consolidation pleural effusi...  No acute cardiopulmonary process
1   Chronic pain noted in lower erector spinae                Palpate       None   Upper iliocostalis thoracis triggers pain alon...                               Nil
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Sorry i was away. I hve thousand of files text files like that. your code only putting the last process data into the pandas dataframe, how can i put all the process data into the dataframe. thanks for your help.

Comment: @MoniruzzamanKhan Please see the updated code, this should provide the functionality you require

Comment: Thanks for help, I have another question, if some of the keywords are missing and I still want to get information of another keywords on the same file and put "NULL" or   " 0 " as values of missing keywords. What I have to do.

Comment: @MoniruzzamanKhan You're welcome. That functionality isn't a quick fix, its probably best if you create a minimal example of what you want done when handling missing keywords and then post another question

Comment: @MoniruzzamanKhan You're welcome. If the post answered your question, please remember to mark it as the accepted answer.